# How to check if condition with for loop from IList Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

When i try to check if condition with `IList` data it is returning error as below.

```
CS1660: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'bool' because it is not a delegate type
```

**Code**

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
   @if (m => m[i].IsSpecial)
   {
       @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].IsActive)
       @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Id)
       @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].Name)
   }
}
```

What goes wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'=>` is the syntax C# uses to specify [lamba expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).  So the order you write the operators is important.

Error is in line

```
  @if (m => m[i].IsSpecial)
```

Convert it to

```
  @if (Model[i].IsSpecial) //Change here if special is bool
```

Comment: I tried it before and when changed it is returning error as  `CS0103: The name 'm' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: @SSS Is you model a list? if yes then try Model[i]

Comment: +1, I changed your answer where i need to check with `Model` instead of `m` and it works, thanks...